# Line split a log file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm no programmer or developer by any stretch of the imagination, and I've come across a Python 3 programming issue that I can't visualize to solve.

I have a firewall/router that uses Suricata as an IDPS that saves log file data in a file named alerts.log. The Suricata logs are filled with hundreds of line entries, such as:

```
11/10/2022-12:47:06.318702  [**] [1:2210038:2] SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}
```

The above is a 1 line entry from one of the Suricata log files.  In that line you will see -

`SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window` and `[1:2210038:2]`

What I really need from those 2 snippets is an entry in a separate text file formatted as:

```
# SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window
1:2210038
```

I've been trying to use the `str.split()` method to accomplish this with no luck.

I've been using the following code as a test in my IDE (PyCharm) to see if I can display the text I need in the format I need it:

```py
infile = open('alerts.log', "r")
print("\n")
for line in infile:
    message = (line.split('[**]')[1].split('] ')[1].strip())
    sid = (line.split(' [')[2])
    print("# " + message)
    print(sid)
print("\n")
```

The above code results in the following which is the closest I've been able to get to what I need -

```
# SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window
1:2210038:2] SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window
```

On the 2nd line, if I could just remove the second colon and everything to the right, that would be what I need.  Anyone have any ideas to assist a non-programmer with this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression that matches the patterns you want:

```py
import re

line = '11/10/2022-12:47:06.318702  [**] [1:2210038:2] SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}'

m = re.search(r'\[(\d+:\d+):\d+] (.*?) \[', line)
if m:
    print('#', m.group(2))
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
# SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window
1:2210038
```

Here's a verbose version if you want to understand the expression.  Note that whitespace has to be explicit in verbose mode.

```py
import re

line = '11/10/2022-12:47:06.318702  [**] [1:2210038:2] SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}'

m = re.search(r'''(?x)       # enable verbose mode (comments)
                  \[         # match a open bracket
                  (\d+:\d+)  # capture digits colon digits
                  :\d+]      # match colon, digits and close bracket
                  \s         # match a whitespace
                  (.*?)      # capture non-greedy everything up to...
                  \s\[       #   whitespace and open bracket.
                  ''', line)
if m:
    print('#', m.group(2))
    print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: The REGEX code you wrote works for me. I've refactored my code to match, however, because there are a lot of duplicate messages and SID lines in the original log file (except of course for the dates at the beginning of the line), the code is printing these duplicates in the format that's needed. I've attempted to write the code to deduplicate the output with no success.  Any ideas on what to change to keep duplicates from being printed? Thank you.

Comment: If you just want unique IDs you could add them to a `set`. Ask a new question and provide sample data lines with duplicates.

Comment: Mark...new post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74843231/dedupe-log-entries

Answer (score 0):

Considering that this log file follow the same pattern you can use this inside your loop

```
.split(' [**] ')[1].split(' ', 1)
```

So your final code result would be like this:

```py
for line in file:
    message = line.split(' [**] ')[1].split(' ', 1)
    print("MESSAGE: {}".format(message[0]))
    print("SID: {}".format(message[1]))
```

And this would be your final result:

> MESSAGE: [1:2210038:2] 
> SID: SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window