# Dedupe Log Entries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not a programmer or developer and I have a Python 3 programming issue that I can't seem to solve.

I have a Suricata log file named alerts.log with examples of the following data inside.  There are hundreds of these lines in the alerts.log file and a lot of the lines are duplicates, such as below, except for the date-time stamps.

```
11/10/2022-08:32:29.891692  [**] [1:2210054:1] SURICATA STREAM excessive retransmissions [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}  
11/10/2022-08:34:21.185990  [**] [1:2210054:1] SURICATA STREAM excessive retransmissions [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}  
11/10/2022-08:34:21.246621  [**] [1:2210054:1] SURICATA STREAM excessive retransmissions [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}  
11/10/2022-12:47:06.318702  [**] [1:2210038:2] SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}  
11/10/2022-12:47:06.537754  [**] [1:2210038:2] SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}  
11/10/2022-12:47:06.969727  [**] [1:2210038:2] SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}  
11/14/2022-10:45:56.543566  [**] [1:2230027:1] SURICATA TLS certificate invalid der [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}  
11/14/2022-10:45:56.555059  [**] [1:2230027:1] SURICATA TLS certificate invalid der [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}  
11/14/2022-10:45:56.555386  [**] [1:2230027:1] SURICATA TLS certificate invalid der [**] [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3] {TCP}
```

I'm interested in writing only the **unique** Message and corresponding `GID:SID` to another file.  The Message and the `GID:SID` on the same line of course go with each other such as:

```
Message = SURICATA STREAM excessive retransmissions  
GID:SID = 1:2210054
```

An example of the Message and corresponding `GID:SID` needed format to be written to another file from the above example data, deduped, would be:

```
\# SURICATA STREAM excessive retransmissions  
1:2210054

\# SURICATA STREAM FIN out of window  
1:2210038

\# SURICATA TLS certificate invalid der  
1:2230027
```

The following code is what I have written, and it does write the output in the format needed to another file, but I can't seem to write the deduped Message with the corresponding `GID:SID`:

```py
content = open('alerts.log', "r").readlines()
sid_outfile = "test.txt"
unique = []
with open(sid_outfile, "w") as f:
    for line in content:
        pattern = re.search(r"\[(\d:\d+):\d] (.*?) \[", line)
        if pattern not in unique:
            unique.append(pattern)
        if unique:
            f.write("# " + pattern.group(2) + "\n")
            f.write(pattern.group(1) + "\n\n")
```

I've also tried the `set()` method with no luck in the code -

```py
unique = set()
unique.add(pattern)
```

Anyone have an ideas on how the code needs to be written in order to write the deduped format needed to another file?  Any assistance would be most helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: All duplicates will be grouped like in your example? *(3 lines one after another)*

Comment: Do you really need python for this?  Seems to me that `sort` would be a better tool.

Comment: Try [this](https://tio.run/##ZY9BasQwDEX3PoVQN3YIhqGbEuhJ4hA8NJ4x2JaxFZKh9OxpJu1Q2gq00uP9r3zjK6Xnl1y2zRWK4HkqTBQq@JipMFwKzfl8E8KnPPPofJiSjRO8QkEbdrjqQBcUNPO/O0@VNa@MQiyer0B5SvK3R4Hdo0bXGgHfc1B/dC3gggdLo@sO1FH5KtfCCD49isq7DIKN5zcLawerrjl4ltg3zYCqPw26cvFZIvSoVPcTOzq9lP1/icY8wfuHSfc1CfUeFS3L5oh4@AbAFk5KqW37BA).

Comment: If you copy the lines at the top of my post into an empty file named alerts.log and run the code, you'll see all of the duplicates in the test.txt file.  I only need to see 1 instance of each unique data point.

sorted just sorts as far as I can tell.

Comment: @tryin2code, that's what I did testing code suggested in [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74843231/10824407#comment132083596_74843231) comment.